# Beyond the Basics:Complex Analysis Topics/textbooks Suggestions

Tags: complex-analysis, soft-question

I am currently taking a semester long Graduate course in Complex Analysis. We have covered Basics of Complex Analysis,Automorphisms of Disc and Upper Half Plane,Riemann Mapping Theorem,Weierstrass and Mittag Leffler's Theorem,Runge Approximation and the structure of ideals in the ring of entire functions. Unfortunately due to lack of time we won't be able to cover Uniformization and Picard Theorems.

What are some important topics that a student taking a course on Complex Analysis should know, and has been left out from whatever I have mentioned has been taught so far. To be honest though, I am very happy with how this course has turned out so far, because I learned a lot interesting results.

Although the CA course that I am taking now is a graduate course, I would, however, not want to be ignorant of important topics within this field. I understand that within the span of a semester it is not possible to cover every important topic in CA. But, your input would be very helpful.

(I am not sure if this is an appropriate forum for a question like this. But, I hope it is not too vague)

Comment: Jeez you must go to a better school than me. We barely covered that and I just finished a two semester graduate sequence.

Comment: I suppose the next step is Riemann Surfaces?